# Why it the Handler statement an unreacherable code?

Tags: android, service, handler, runnable

This is the code of the service class I created. It gives me an error of Unreachable code at the handler.post(timedtask) line. I have commented it in bold below. Please help me out with this. Its killing me!
    public class ServerChecker extends Service {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    Intent resultIntent;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable timedtask;
    String bus_no;
    int mystoppageindex;

```
public ServerChecker() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();



bus_no = PrefsHelper.getFromPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext(),  "BUSNO", "");
mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setTicker("Your bus is arriving")
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("My notification")
.setContentText("Hello World!")
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
.setAutoCancel(true);
resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
String url = Config.url + "arrivalwarning.php?bus_no=3-C";

final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new  Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

mystoppageindex = Integer.parseInt(PrefsHelper.getFromPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "STOPPAGEINDEX", ""));

try {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
int currentstoppageindex = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("stoppage_index"));

                if (mystoppageindex - currentstoppageindex == 2) {

                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MyApplication.getAppContext());
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoginActivity.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager)      getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    handler = new Handler();

    timedtask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("TAG","Runnable");

          //  VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);

            handler.postDelayed(timedtask, 60000);
        }

    };






}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    handler.post(timedtask); **// WHY IS THIS LINE AN ERROR UNREACHABLE CODE**
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(timedtask);
}
}
```

Comment: "WHY IS THIS LINE AN ERROR UNREACHABLE CODE" - Because you have it after a `return` statement. Move it to before that.

Answer (score 0):

you have this here:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    handler.post(timedtask); **// WHY IS THIS LINE AN ERROR UNREACHABLE CODE**
}
```

so to answer your question we need to know how are you expecting java to execute a statement in a method that already returned...